# How can I take the input and insert it into LINKED LIST in java?

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to make a three different linked list. I will determine the first ones inputs but for the other two I want to ask the user for the inputs and then insert them into a linked list. Can anyone help me with how to do that? So far I could only write this code

```
package homework001;

 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.LinkedList;
 import java.util.ListIterator;

public class morph {

    public static LinkedList<String> list;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
        list.add("10");
        list.add("34");
        list.add("1");
        list.add("97");
        list.add("5");
        list.add("62");     

   }
 }
```

Comment: use a `Scanner` to take the user input. How many times do you want the user to keep entering data?

Comment: If you google "java user input from console" you'll find plenty of tutorials about using Scanner

Comment: Yes I used Scanner  but after that how am I gonna insert all the data that I've got into Linked List that is my rela question

Comment: @LeenaliLi show the code which is using the scanner then. ^^.

Answer (score 2):

I think we can simply take user input in LinkedList by using
this method -> ***listname.add(sc.nextInt());***

code for the implementation is below! **thank you** :)

```
public class LL_userInput {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedList<Integer> ll = new LinkedList<>(); //creating list
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); //creating scanner for total elements to be inserted in list
        System.out.println("enter total count of elements -> ");
        int num = sc.nextInt(); // user will enter total elements
        
        while(num>0) { 
        ll.add(sc.nextInt());
        num--;  // decrement till the index became 0    
        }
        sc.close();
        System.out.println(ll);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't understand from the comments here is a simple example ;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();//declare your list
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);//create a scanner
    System.out.print("Enter the Nbr of element : ");
    int nbr = scan.nextInt();//read the number of element
    scan.nextLine();
    do {
        list.add(scan.nextLine());//read and insert into your list in one shot
        nbr--;//decrement the index
    } while (nbr > 0);//repeat until the index will be 0

    scan.close();//close your scanner
    System.out.println(list);//print your list

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I didn't at first. I'm a beginner. Sorry for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Using [scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), you can get input from any source. To read from console use

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while(!sc.hasNextInt()) sc.next();
int number = sc.nextInt();

for(i=0; i< number; i++)
    myList.add(sc.next());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
class LinkedList{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc= new Scanner (System.in );
    LinkedList<Integer>list=new 
LinkedList<>();
    System.out.println("Enter how many 
elements you want");
    int num=sc.nextInt();
for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
       System.out.println("Enter element 
at index "+i);
list.add(sc.nextInt());
   }
   
 System.out.print(list+" ");

}
}
```

Comment: It's very simple code to understand as beginners